# How can I make a Jmeter HTTP request with an Enum as Request Parameter?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jmeter

I have a Spring Controller with this signature

`public ResponseEntity<blabla> find(@RequestParam Long id, @RequestParam Long version, @RequestParam CheckedItemType type)`

I am trying to make an http request with Jmeter setting the third parameter as:
type=0 text/plain and I get a 400 error code cause the controller can't cast a String to CheckedItemType.

Any idea about how I can solve this?

Comment: JMeter only looks at the traffic flowing over the wire [something that you get in Wireshark or similar network sniffers]. You are viewing this at the application layer level. Please share from other tools how your request body is looking like when it is delivered over the wire.

Answer (score 0):

Here, is an example:

```
public enum Modes {
    ALPHA, BETA;
}
```

String to enum Converter:

```
public class StringToEnumConverter implements Converter<String, Modes> {

    @Override
    public Modes convert(String from) {
        return Modes.valueOf(from);
    }
}
```

Aregister our Converter:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {


  @Override
  public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
       registry.addConverter(new StringToEnumConverter());
  }
}
```

Comment: is there a way to tell Jmeter to send something that will be seen as an int instead of a String? The endopoint I have shown works in production, is just the integration with Jmeter which throws this error